# Encode an image file as multipart/form-data in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, multipartform-data

I need to encode an image file as multipart/form-data in python 3 to upload it to Localbitcoins. Localbitcoins provides the API to post the file, so I only need to encode my image as multipart/form-data. The argument to be used is a dict with key 'document' and  a value that must be of type file encoded with multipart/form-data:

argument = {'document':value}

So, how I transform myfile.jpg in my disk into a value encoded as multipart/form-data to upload it to Localbitcoins?

Comment: What do you mean with "Localbitcoins provides the API to post the file"? The REST API or the python library?

Comment: The pyhton library